# Pricing Government Bonds use OIS or Gov. ZC Yields?

Tags: fixed-income, bond, ois

I am pricing government bonds ranging from JPN, GERMANY, UK, India to NIGERIA, MXN, ARG, Brazil etc.

What is the better approach to use OIS for each currency or build a curve using government zero coupon rates?

Also, where from I can get OIS rates for different currencies?
Looking for a paid source (BBG, markit) as well as a free source?

thanks.

Comment: You can ask the help desk to get your answers if you have BBG. Also, the prices are quoted. To compare against curves, you can use CRVF and the like, with custom SRCH bond searches. One general thing though, why would you price a government bond with OIS, if the latter has nothing to do with bonds?

Comment: @AKdemy thanks I know I can use BBG help, but would still like to understand it better so hoping to get more understanding here. Why would I use OIS, as I read its better than gov. yields?Copy/paste a comment :"Choosing swap curves over bonds curves in Euroland also has two major advantages; 1) it allows consistent valuation from country to country even when the respective countries' GBs have considerably different yield levels, due to each respective state's financial position. 2) Swap curves are well defined, smooth and have an active market, whereas some countries' bond curves are spars....

Comment: What do you mean by "pricing" bonds? For most people, this means that you can observe some quotes for some binds, and want to guess quotes for other bonds that are similar but don't have observable quotes. If thus is the goal, then an obvious smell test is, does your methodology match the observable quotes. Do you?

Comment: @DimitriVulis yes that's what I meant by pricing,also price verification, I was told for ie. T bills better to use OIS rates than t bills, if so, does it apply to other currencies?

Comment: a "T-Bill" is zero-coupon governemnt debt instrument. Are you (mis)using this term to refer to coupon instruments as well? In a few countries, notably Brazil, because of tax rules, zero-coupon government debt (Letra do Tesouro Nacional - LTN)) has a separate yield curve from coupon instrumemts (Notas do Tesouro Nacional - Série F). But in the U.S., it's one treasry curve. so, if you discount the single cash flow of a U.S. T-bill, the face value at maturity, using the OIS curve, do you match the observable quote for the T-bill?

Comment: @DimitriVulis I used the t bills term to refer to zero coupon debt instruments, if I discount T bills using the OIS rates, I don't match the observable quotes,but what if I build a spread curve T bill - OIS using observable t bills, and use the OIS curve + spread to price t bills, otherwise not sure what was the meaning of my copy/paste text in my 1st comment.

Comment: Let's imagine an emerging market where: a swap curve (like OIS or SOFR) is observable to 10 years; the treasury previously issued bonds with maturities up to 5y, and they're observable in the secondary market; now the government plans to issue 7y debt; you want to predict the yield of the new bond. The spread between swaps and existing treasuries is likely to be close to constant, so you add it to  the observable 7y swap rate. You introduce less noise than if you ignored the shape of the swap curve and extrapolated from just the treasury yields. But in many emerging markets, the treasury

Comment: curve is actually better observable and for longer maturities than some swap curve. E.g. in Argentina, there really is no swap curve at all. In Brazil,a swap curve (DI) is only up to 10 years, while liquid treasuries have longer maturities.

Comment: @DimitriVulis Thank you Dimitri, so if I want to price (or do price verification) an fx gov bill/bond, I determine what has a better observability swap curve or treasury curve, if its swap curve, I add the treasury spread to it (likely close to constant), as for Brazil would it mean for 10 years tenors to use swap curve and, the longer tenors go with treasuries? thanks!

Comment: @DimitriVulis I would appreciate it if you could confirm, thank you!